# Implement a tree view like for storing files in Sub folders

Tags: c#

I have a series of upload controls in my WebApp on different pages. The documents uploaded are classified into the following folder: Each folder represents a page.

```
- main 
-- Customers
--- CustomerId 
---- ClaimId 
-- Staff
--- StaffId
---- StaffClaimId
-- Vehicle
--- Vehicle Type 
---- Vehicle Id
```

I have the following code that creates a folder:

```
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadbox1, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Negotiatedtarrifuploadbox1, string folderName, FileUploadParameter uploadParam)
    {
        var uploadbox = (uploadbox1 != null) ? uploadbox1 : Negotiatedtarrifuploadbox1;
        if (uploadbox != null)
        {

            string targetFolder = new FileManagement().PathSave(FileType.documents) + "\\" + folderName;        public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadbox, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Negotiatedtarrifuploadbox1, string folderName, FileUploadParameter uploadParam)
    {
        var uploadbox = (uploadbox1 != null) ? uploadbox1 : Negotiatedtarrifuploadbox1;
        if (uploadbox != null)
        {
            string targetFolder = new FileManagement().PathSave(FileType.documents) + "\\" + folderName;
```

And this:

```
    public string PathType(FileType type, FileHierarchy hierarchy)
    {
        var path = "";
        switch (type)
        {
            case FileType.images:
                path = "/images/";
                break;
            default:
                path = "/";
                break;
        }

        return path;
    }
```

How I can I create folder based on the web page I am and add the files uploaded in the respective folder?

Comment: From code above, the problem is how to set `folderName` to assemble the full path matching tree view?

Answer (score 0):

This code will represent the subfolder+subfiles view

```
    class Program
    {
        private static void PrintSubFolders(DirectoryInfo dir, string separator = "-")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(separator + dir.FullName);
            var directories = dir.GetDirectories();

            var files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(separator + file.FullName);
            }

            foreach (var folder in directories)
            {
                PrintSubFolders(folder, separator+separator[0]);
            }
        }

        private static void PrintSubFolders(string path)
        {
            PrintSubFolders(new DirectoryInfo(path));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintSubFolders(@"C:\Users\Vladislav\Documents\GIT Repos");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is not complete. But I'll assume the whole goal is to define targetFolder.
Try something like this ([Template method pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern)):

```
public class BasePage
{ 
    public virtual string FolderName { get { return ""; } }

    // This behavior is common for every page. It sets the way targetFolder is calculated, using FolderName.
    // Every class inheriting this base class will know where it stores file will know it and override FolderName as below. 
    // All you do is to update existing classes (don't forget inheritance and virtual/override keywords).
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadbox1, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Negotiatedtarrifuploadbox1, FileUploadParameter uploadParam)
    {
        var uploadbox = (uploadbox1 != null) ? uploadbox1 : Negotiatedtarrifuploadbox1;
        if (uploadbox != null)
        {

            // Note FolderName property is used instead of parameter in original question.
            string targetFolder = new FileManagement().PathSave(FileType.documents) + "\\" + FolderName;
            // Missing code using targetFolder path
        }
    }
}

public class Customers : BasePage 
{
    public override string FolderName { get { return "\Customers"; } }
    // Your other properties and methods specific to this page.
}

public class CustomerId  : BasePage 
{
    public override string FolderName { get { return "\Customers\CustomerId "; } }
    // Your other properties and methods specific to this page.
}

public class Staff : BasePage 
{
    public override string FolderName { get { return "\Staff"; } }
    // Your other properties and methods specific to this page.
}

public class StaffId  : BasePage 
{
    public override string FolderName { get { return "\Staff\StaffId "; } }
    // Your other properties and methods specific to this page.
}
```

This way you define your logic in one place (how you generate path), leaving child classes to say where in the tree file should be saved. Good luck.